# Проблема с post запросом node js. SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: node.js, веб-программирование, express

Посылаю POST запрос на сторонний ресурс. Запрос не обрабатывается из-за синтаксической ошибки: `Unexpected token .`

Мне было бы понятно, если бы запрос выдавал ошибку с любыми параметрами, но это не так. С такими параметрами проходит без ошибок:

`act=3&page=5&vv%5B1%5D=%C3%EB%E8%F6%E8%ED&tek_page=1&tek_page_lec=1&tek_id_farm=125108&id_apteka_raion_area=0&id_apteka_raion_city=1`

Параметры ,когда запрос не проходит(bodyS):

```
act=3&page=5&vv%5B1%5D=%C0%E7%E5%EB%E8%EA&tek_page=1&tek_page_lec=1&tek_id_farm=98159&id_apteka_raion_area=0&id_apteka_raion_city=1


router.get('/:lek_href/:lek_pharm', function(req, res){
var bodyS = 'act=3&page=5&vv%5B1%5D=%C0%E7%E5%EB%E8%EA&tek_page=1&tek_page_lec=1&tek_id_farm=98159&id_apteka_raion_area=0&id_apteka_raion_city=1';
request.post({
  url: 'http://tabletka.online/index.php?page=5', 
  headers: {'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
  encoding: null,
  body: bodyS},
  function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, result){
    if (err) {
    return console.error('Failed: ', err);
    res.send(err);
    }
    console.log('конец запроса');
  });
});
```

Подскажите, в чём может быть причина ошибки?

Comment: Добавьте к вопросу пример параметров, с которыми получаете ошибку

Comment: Причина ошибки, очевидно, в коде, обрабатывающем запрос, на том сайте, куда Вы посылаете запрос.

Comment: Ну и попутное замечание (не связанное с вопросом): строчка `res.send(err);` в вашем коде не будет выполняться ни при каких условиях.

Comment: На счет res.send() спасибо ,после return код не выполняется.
А на счет запроса , на том сайте он все равно обрабатывается, почему у меня он не обрабатывается - не знаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причина ошибки: 
В запросе `/:lek_pharm` данные имели в строке слэш => отображение происходило не `'/:lek_href/:lek_pharm'` ,а `'/:lek_href/:lek_pharm/...'`